# Integration by parts in the conserved functionals of the Euler Equations for inviscid flow

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

So I am working through Peter Olver's book Application of Lie Groups to differential equations, and I have a rather basic question on integration by parts that I have been stuck on. The overall question is finding the conserved functionals for the Euler equations of inviscid flow in two dimensions (on page 450-451). Now they have this integral
$$\mathscr P_a =\int \alpha(t) y\omega dx\, dy = \int \alpha(t) u dx \, dy, \ \ \ \ \ \omega = v_x - u_y.$$
and $u,v$ are the two depedant variables each with two independant spacial variables $x,y$.
The author said he got the second integral by applying integration by parts, however, I am not quite seeing it because this is what I would do in applying integration by parts
$$ \int \alpha y \omega \;dxdy = \int \alpha y (v_x -u_y) \; dydx = \int \alpha y v_x \; dydx - \int \alpha yu_y \; dydx$$
$$= \int \alpha y v_x  \; dydx -\int_X [\alpha y \cdot u]|_Y dx + \int \alpha \cdot u \; dydx$$
now I'm thinking I could take the first integral $\int \alpha y v_x \; dydx = \int \alpha yv_x \; dxdy = \int_Y[\alpha y \cdot v]|_X \; dy$. Where $X, Y$ are our domain. Now from here, I am stuck, this is the Euler equation in two dimensions and unless $u$ and $v$ decay rapidly fast on the boundary $X$ and $Y$ then it doesn't seem that what I am doing is correct. Now nowhere in this problem did it state this condition, so that is why I am not sure about this. If somebody could confirm what I am saying is correct or explain to me where I went wrong that could be fantastic, thank you!

Comment: The Euler equations on a domain usually come with the no penetration boundary condition $u\cdot n=0$ where $n$ is the normal to the boundary. I can’t fully get the notation you / he is using but does that answer the question?